# Trying to do a simple search and count for the input word in C++

Tags: c++, text, count, line, cpu-word

Here is my code this far

```
int main()
{
string word;
int wordcount = 0;
cout << "Enter a word to be counted in a file: ";
cin >> word;
string s;
ifstream file ("Names.txt");
while (file >> s)
        {
            if(s == word)
            ++ wordcount;
        }
int cnt = count( istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(), word());
cout << cnt << endl;
}
```

File Names.txt has loads of words and numbers. I do not quite understand how does istream iterator count words but I got some results with it. The only error I get at the moment is

```
in function int main 
error: no match for call to `(std::string) ()'
```

and that occurs in line starting with "int cnt". I've tried for a few hours but I am not that familiar with C++, it seems I'd have to create an extra string or change word string somehow.

I'd appreciate any help!!

Comment: The message is clear: `word` is an `std::string` and you are calling `word()`. You can't do that with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not correct:

```
 int cnt = count( istream_iterator<string>(infile), 
            istream_iterator<string>(), word());
                                          //^^^^^Error
```

should be:

```
int cnt = count( istream_iterator<string>(infile), 
                istream_iterator<string>(), word);
```

Meanwhile, remove the following part:

```
while (infile >> s)
{
    if(s == word)
    ++ wordcount;
}
```

Since otherwise, `file` will be pointed at end of file when you using the iterator with count algorithm. You should either using loop or iterator,  not both at the same time.

Comment: Mhmm thanks, I have these headers included. So I don't need the wordcount at all with iterator? It just counts?

Also that is how a single line of my file looks like, with some 20 000 lines.

"aabel","1 Mo.","VT","1 Mo. 4:25"

These are Bible names. At the moment I am getting an output of 0 each time when searching for e.g adam, aabraham, noa, jacob . Can you see why?

Comment: @JackLongen You don't need to word count loop at all since they are doing the same thing. Using the count algo is enough. Have you removed the while loop? I tried it, it works perfectly.

Comment: I removed the while loop and program both works with only while loop or only iterator. Problem at the moment is that if I search for example aabel then it can't find it although the name is included in at least 7 lines in following form : "aabel"

Comment: Okay hmmm, rohitsan answered to that so I'll have to try reading from the beginning of file.

Comment: @JackLongen if your input is aabel without quote, it won't be able to find since it does exact match, if the word in file has quotes, therefore, you have to do the same thing

Comment: I thought this might be the problem. Currently I still get the output of 0. I am not sure if I should do it with loop, to start from beginning of file or modify the iterator.

Comment: @JackLongen You can only use while loop or count. not both, if you put while loop before the count, it will move the pointer to end of file, at that time, when you call count, you read nothing from file. That's why in my answer I said remove while loop.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the loop and count order now. So I made a few tests. If I only use while loop (cout << wordcount) and get an ouput of 0, do you think the problem is in search term? Cause I haven't gotten back a different result yet.

Comment: @JackLongen most likely yes. Try to use iterator and stl algorithm, which is usually better in terms of performance.

Comment: Thank you for help, got it working now! Have a new problem now but I'll create a new thread for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: word().  You are trying to call operator() on an std::string but there is no such member function in std::string.

change your statement to:

```
int cnt = count(istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(), word);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an output of 0 because of the while loop that tacp asked you to remove.  The while loop advances the file pointer to end of file so the count algorithm starts and ends at end of file effectively doing nothing.